# Hostpath volume not mounting on kubernetes running on Docker-desktop for windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, kubernetes-pod

I am running kubernetes on Docker-desktop for windows. I am connecting to the cluster from my WSL.
all my pods are running correctly. I am trying to mount a volume on my jupyterlab (pod) using hostpath. below is my config

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jupyter
  labels:
    app: jupyter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jupyter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jupyter
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jupyter
        image: jupyter:1.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mydir
            mountPath: /notebooks
      volumes:
        - name: mydir
          hostPath:
            # directory location on host
            path: /home/<myuser>/data
            # this field is optional
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

The pod starts without any issues. but i dont see the notbooks which i have kept in my hostpath onto my jupyter labs and vice versa( if i save a notebook in jupyter lab it does not get saved to my hostpath).

i followed the tutorial on https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

i want to point out that i am using the @FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook:python-3.7.6" as my docker image.

i tried mounting /home/jovyan/ but it was giving me access related errors while starting the pod. so i reverted back to "/notebooks"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an issue with how the path is being written on Windows, I see the issue reported in the references below.

Solution:

- If your file is in say C: drive, it should be converted to the below

```
/host_mnt/c/path/to/my/folder
```

- If the above does not work you may want to remove the "type: DirectoryOrCreate" and retry.

References:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59876#issuecomment-628955935
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1703#issuecomment-366701358 .

Comment: i tried both. neither of them worked. i even tried to mount the wsl path (not windows) and that too is not working. The pods is starting without any issue, but doesnt show the files

Comment: I agree Seeker.  As of 2023, neither of those work for me on Windows either.

Comment: @DBSand, curious if I should expect to find one of those paths such as described in the articles via a cygwin or git bash prompt.  I wonder if docker changed yet again and the mount path is changed again.  Should we be able to navigate to the host path on the host using that extra prefix to confirm how it is setup?  I happen to be using the Docker that comes with Rancher desktop but it is a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WSL based engine on windows, the path should be `/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/<folder>`

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.  The above answers are on the right track.  A prefix such as /mnt or /host_mnt will both appear to work.  However, I had written my yaml file incorrectly as the author did.  Once you apply that yaml file with 'kubectl apply -f filename.yaml' it will create a volume mount within the WSL, but it will be empty.  Now if you use "kubectl delete" to clean up the resources and try again with a corrected yaml file, it will still appear to fail.  That is because the default retention policy seems to imply that the WSL will not actually delete the directory it created.

I verified using command such as these which show that the same directory under /host_mnt appeared to be empty, but the actual directory on the host had the expected file. FYI, I've no idea why I couldn't view the host_mnt sub-directories directly with 'wsl -e ls /host_mnt'.  I had to open a git bash terminal to a directory on my hard disk and then use the relative path navigation to backtrack to the root directory.

```
wsl -e ls ../../../../host_mnt/v/TrustedData/test-data  # readme.txt doesn't exist
ls /v/TrustedData/test-data   # readme.txt does exist where I expect
readme.txt
```

I then manually deleted the directory on the wsl using this command

```
wsl -e rmdir ../../../../host_mnt/v/TrustedData/test-data
```

Now I corrected my yaml file to look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: manual
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/v/TrustedData/mnt"
```

Now when I created the volume mount the WSL recreated the directory with the files that I prepopulated.  I then used this command to attach to my pod.

```
winpty kubectl -it exec task-pv-pod -- bash
```

Navigating to the /usr/share/nginx/html directory within the pod I could see the expected index.html file and the curl command worked as expected.  I had been following the tutorial at https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/ so my pod and volume claim specs were the same as described by that article.

Reference to reclaim policy: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming

This problem seems to be Windows specific due to how the WSL mounts a host path from the host into a VM.  Deleting a kubernetes volume claim and volume doesn't automatically reclaim that resource.

Comment: Thank you shawn1874! Your solution worked for me. What I did was:
1. Open bash terminal in windows like you did.
2. Enter the command : wsl  wsl ls ../../../c
3. Just find the folder that I want to share. For example C:\shared
4. In my yaml file I've modified the hostPath like this:
  hostPath:  # for demonstration purposes only; not suitable for production
     path: "/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/shared"